# SSH does not seem to recognise keys generated on a mac

Tags: ssh

I have a pair of public/private keys that were generated on a Mac to log on a HPC cluster.  When used on the Mac as

```
ssh -i user_key user@hpc.server
```

the whole thing works, that is, a passphrase is requested, and the right passphrase is accepted by the server.  On the other hand, when the very same keys are copied on an Ubuntu machine the passphrase is not accepted by the server (yes, I do type the correct passphrase!).

This is just incomprehensible to me, especially because a different set of keys, generated on a mac and copied to a Ubuntu machine do work flawlessly.

Now the gritty details.  The Mac where the keys were generated runs MacOS 10.13.6, OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2.

The Ubuntu machine is running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS and OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Comment: Could it be a keyboard layout / language / locale issue with the passphrase?

Comment: Nope, those are the same, and the passphrase is purely alphanumeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by LibreSSL 2.6.2, generating a key that was not valid for other versions.  The only workaround was to generate a new set of keys on Ubuntu.